# Usar Get/Set de una clase en otra

Tags: java, poo, clase, get

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public class Camion {
private int numEjes;
private int toneladasCarga;


public int getNumEjes() {
    return this.numEjes;
}
public void setNumEjes(int numEjes) {
    this.numEjes = numEjes;
}

public int getToneladasCarga() {
    return this.toneladasCarga;
}
public void setToneladasCarga(int toneladasCarga) {
    this.toneladasCarga = toneladasCarga;
}
```

---

```
public class Peaje {

public int calcularPeaje(){
    double Peaje= ((3*getNumEjes())+(10*getToneladasCarga);
}
```

Necesito hacer un método dentro de Peaje, que me permita establecerlo en función del numero de ejes y de y las toneladas de carga, es decir Peaje=((3ejes)+(10toneladas)).

He intentado crear el método llamando a los gets de la clase camión pero no entiendo qué debo hacer para que lo haga correctamente.

Comment: Creo que debe ser getToneladosCarga() en lugar de getToneladosCarga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pásale al método `calcularPeaje` un objeto de tipo `Camion` y luego calcula el peaje utilizando esa instancia:

```
public int calcularPeaje(Camion camion) {
    return 3 * camion.getNumEjes() + 10 * camion.getToneladasCarga();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Para usar los metodos de una clase primero tienes que crear un objeto de dicha clase y despues usar los metodos de dicha clase. Como asumo que lo que que dices es que el camion tiene 3 ejes y 10 toneladas haria algo asi:

```
public int calcularPeaje(){
    Camion camion = new Camion();
    camion.setNumEjes(3);
    camion.setToneladasCarga(10)
    double Peaje= ((camion.getNumEjes())+(camion.getToneladasCarga());
}
```

Con los Set establecemos los atributos del camion y los Get nos los proporcionan para usarlos

Comment: No tiene sentido crear un objeto para guardarle un valor que luego vas a leer en el mismo sitio. En todo caso, deberías cambiar la declaración del método para que reciba el objeto como parámetro, puesto que si no, acabas antes directamente hardcodeando los valores en la multiplicación. Además, has puesto una suma en vez de una multiplicación en la asignación a `Peaje`, las variables no deberían empezar por mayúscula y por último, ese método no es válido ya que lo has declarado `int` y no devuelve nada... además de que `Peaje` lo declaraste como `double` por lo que sería inválido devolverlo.